# How to get the first row with value in range

Tags: google-apps-script

In a google script with spreadsheet, I need to get the first row with a non blank value in a range. 
But I'm a little bit blocked, I don't find a way to get my first row with a value.

For example in my code, I'm trying to loop to find every 4 line, the first rows with value.
Any idea ? 
Thank you !

```
function findStartDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(roadmapSS);

  var sourceLength = ss.getSheetByName(trelloSortSS).getLastRow()-1;
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = columnToLetter(column);

  for (var h = 11; h < (sourceLength*4)+11; h+=4) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(h, 11, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
    // here I need to get my first row
  }
}
```

Comment: Bit hard to underatand what doesn't work. Also, you might want to clean up some redundancies. For example you store last column index twice and still retrieve it inside the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script that find the row number for the first row with nonempty column C. Modify as needed.

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i][2]) {   // index 2 = 3rd column = C
    break;
  }
}
Logger.log("First nonempty row is " + (i+1))  // i is 0-based but row numbers are 1-based
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on useruser6655984's answer here

```
function getFirstColumn(){  
  for (var m = 0; m < data.length; m++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
      if (data[m][j]) {   
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return j+1
}
```

You can find first Row;

```
function getFirstRow(firstColumn){ // firstColumn will be the j+1 from getFirstColumn
  for (var m = 0; m < data.length; m++) {
    if(data[m][firstColumn]){
      break
    }
  }
  return m+1
}
```